# I can get audio.currentTime but not set it (in Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

This is driving me crazy. Here is the code I use to set current time:

```
$("#audio").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mr_waveform_skip(e)
});

function mr_waveform_skip(event) {
    clientX = event.clientX;
    left = event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    clickoffset = clientX - left;
    percent = clickoffset/event.currentTarget.offsetWidth
    audio_duration = audio_element.duration;
    duration_seek = percent*audio_duration;
    audio_element.currentTime = duration_seek;
    // audio_element.currentTime = 10;
    console.log('CLICK: ' + duration_seek + ' Element: ' + audio_element + ' CurrentTime: ' + audio_element.currentTime);
}
```

I cannot seem to **set** `audio_element.currentTime` only **get** it!

And worse, it works in fireFox! Chrome restarts at 0, no matter what.

This is what the above code produces in Firefox console:

```
CLICK: 63.82905432385121 Element: [object HTMLAudioElement] CurrentTime: 3.849546
```

And in Chrome:

```
CLICK: 63.82905432385121 Element: [object HTMLAudioElement] CurrentTime: 3.849546
```

See? The same one! We can see that Chromes sees the HTML audio element (since it can *get* the value). If I do `audio_element.currentTime = 10;` it still does not work (**in Chrome**, Firefox loyally restarts at 10)..

Comment: Try calling audio.stop(), then audio.currentTime = 10, then audio.play().

Comment: I guess you meant `audio.pause()` but yes, it works... In Firefox. Chrome keeps restarting at 0 :[

Comment: Did you try with a different audio codec?

Comment: @MartinAdámek There is no stop() method on the audio element.

Comment: @k3N You mean  switch from ogg to mp3? I did not though of that, some time ago they were discrepancies in audio codecs support among FF & Chrome, but I though this was sorted... Is it not? Tha would be tough, because it *cannot* be mp3 for legal reasons.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/h40y2eqz/ If you use that media file in your own code, does it work? I am trying to determine if the problem is specific to some code you haven't shown, or specific to the media file you're using.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for the fiddle, you are right, this is unreproducible. I'm trying with the generic ogg file.

Comment: @apsillers I'll be damned, it works. Just post an answer along the lines of "maybe you ogg file is weird" so I can accept it. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/currentTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly when I tested it with with an Ogg file from Wikipedia.. If that really is all of your code, then this problem appears to be caused by some kind of corruption or unexpected format in your media file.

You will not be able to fix this problem with code; you will need to produce a new media file that your browser can process correctly. Perhaps try using a different piece of audio software (or different settings) to produce or re-process the media file.

Comment: It was precisely my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the format isn't the problem:

I've bumped into this problem in Chrome a couple of times today. Wasted so much time trying to solve it. (Version 55.x)

The solution is to restart Chrome. After countless page refreshes the value is suddenly not set. It's probably some cache bug. I would stress that using a development server supporting range requests is also a good idea.

If I'm not running Node or Django I use : https://github.com/danvk/RangeHTTPServer