# Something about the way I'm managing this file download breaks seeking in Chrome audio player

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, media

I have an MVC 5 controller action that retrieves audio data and downloads it to the client. Previously it was some aspx.cs code that had its own problems before I updated it to the following:

```
// Support byte range headers for Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377121/1106497
long fSize = audio.Length;
long startbyte = 0;
long endbyte = fSize - 1;
int statusCode = 200;
if ((Request.Headers["Range"] != null)) {
    // Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
    string[] range = Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
    startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
    if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "") {
        endbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);
    }
    //If the start byte is not equal to zero, that means the user is requesting partial content.
    if (startbyte != 0 || endbyte != fSize - 1 || range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "") {
        // Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.                                    
        statusCode = 206;
    }
}
long desSize = endbyte - startbyte + 1;
// Headers
Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
if (AudioIsWAV(audio)) {
    Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
}

Response.AddHeader("Content-Accept", Response.ContentType);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", desSize.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, endbyte, fSize));

// Send the Data
var stream = new MemoryStream(audio, (int)startbyte, (int)desSize);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, Response.ContentType);
```

Since I updated the action to this it has worked better in all ways except that Chrome's audio player can no longer seek. When you try to adjust where you are in the file it always jumps back to the start.

The closest issue I could find in my research is the following: [I can get audio.currentTime but not set it (in Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351252/i-can-get-audio-currenttime-but-not-set-it-in-google-chrome) where the problem was determined to be a corrupt file. However the files themselves worked before I adjusted how they're being sent.

It works fine in other browsers, and when I put a different source into the same player that seeks fine. I believe that it has to be something wrong with the file I'm sending from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://sitefinitydevelopment.com/blog/here-is-how-to-make-chrome-seek-through-your-audio-files-in-sitefinity.html

The above article gave me an idea to try out. I changed my status code to a `206` even when I'm sending the entire range of the file, and that fixed it. For some reason, a status code `200` breaks seeking in chrome's audio player.